# Docker error Cannot find module 'strapi-plugin-upload/package.json'

Tags: docker, strapi

I'm using DockStation to create an instance of strapi+mysql.
I created everything using the guide at the link: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/installation/docker,

Here the code of my docker-compose about strapi:

```yaml
    version: '2'
    services:
      strapi:
        image: strapi/strapi
        environment:
          - DATABASE_CLIENT=mysql
          - DATABASE_HOST=strapiDB
          #- DATABASE_FILENAME=/data/strapi.db
          - DATABASE_NAME=strapi
          - DATABASE_USERNAME=strapi
          - DATABASE_PASSWORD=strapi
          - JWT_SECRET=pippo
          - ADMIN_JWT_SECRET=pluto
          - APP_KEYS=paperino
          #NODE_ENV=
        volumes:
          - './data:/data'
        platform: linux/amd64
        ports:
          - '1337:1337'
        depends_on:
          - strapiDB
```

here is my full docker-compose.yml file: https://pastebin.com/33vvf5iX

When I try to start the project I get this error: https://pastebin.com/LxsdfSpj

Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What is "this error"? Also, what have you tried to resolve it?